# How can I detect if IE8 is running in compatibility view?

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-8

Is there anyway to determine if an IE8 browser has compatibility view switched on?

I can't seem to find anything on Google, and so I'm wondering if this is a piece of information that is available...

Why you ask!? I'm trying to track down a bug in our application.  I'm piecing through the Elmah logs and there seems to be a trend; this error is generally thrown by IE8.  I tried to repo the defect in my copy of IE8, but couldn't. I want to narrow down the culprits, and thought this might be a way to do it.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you need to know?

Answer (score 18):

In Javascript, use document.documentMode

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988%28VS.85%29.aspx for details.

Comment: This won't help if page is in Quirks mode

Comment: I used this and it worked. if(document.documentMode && document.documentMode < 8) {...}

Comment: @Zafer - I used that and it was perfect.  Thank you and Thank you @alohci

Answer (score 7):

Evidently IE8 has some new properties

> document.documentMode

and

> document.compatMode

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988(VS.85).aspx

Comment: compatMode is a legacy property, and isn't very useful here. It tells you whether the page is in quirks mode.

Answer (score 3):

Check for the "Trident/4.0" in the userAgent. It should be present for IE-8 only.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/33e0ed49-11fb-4d91-857c-a35496e90075

Comment: Also, check for Trident/5.0 in case it's IE 9.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using:

```
try{ JSON } catch (e){ alert("Compatibility Mode Detected")  }
```

The `JSON` object was defined in `IE 8`, so in `IE 7` or when in `Compatibility Mode` an error is thrown and caught.

I like that this works every time and it's one line.

Comment: Yes this is Javascript.  I still use this to this day to kick out people who use ie7.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @Tommy's answer,  use feature detection (alert is optional of course, I use a nice div or inline message somewhere):

```
if(typeof document.documentMode !== 'undefined') { // checks if this is IE 8 or >
         if(document.documentMode < 8) {  // check if in compat mode 
             // add code here to inform user that they need to turn off compatiblity view
             alert("Click ALT-T then compat view etc...");  
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive it is contained in the User Agent string:

"A new tag in the User Agent string allows for detection of clients viewing your site in Compatibility View. This tag is also present in the “normal” Internet Explorer 8 User Agent string."

"In the event that a user selects Compatibility View for your site, you can “bring them back” to your desired layout mode via use of the version targeting  tag / HTTP header. A new content value, ‘IE=EmulateIE8’, rounds out the list of supported values and assists in this particular scenario."

More information here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208837/how-can-i-detect-if-ie8-is-running-in-compatibility-view/1208951#1208951: IE7 produces the same User Agent as IE8 in compatibility mode, so user agent doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In MVC/ASP Request.Browser.Version returns "7.0" regardless of version when in Compatibility View otherwise it returns the browser version.

You can also use Request.Browser.Browser to check that it's IE

```
Request.Browser.Version
Request.Browser.Browser
```

Answer (score -1):

Very simple method - press F12 , it will open developer tool bar . After menus you will see the Browser  mode. Which will clearly tell that it is in IE8 mode or IE7 compatible mode.

Comment: it maybe that you don't have access to the machine which the page is being viewed on.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(preg_match('/(?i)msie/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
if(preg_match('/(?i)Trident\/5/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    echo "IE9";
}
elseif(preg_match('/(?i)Trident\/4/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    echo "IE8";
}
elseif(!preg_match('/(?i)Trident\/4/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) AND preg_match('/(?i)msie 7/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    echo "IE7";
}
elseif(preg_match('/(?i)msie [1-6]/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    echo "IE1 à IE6";
}}
```

Comment: its PHP, it's using regex to compare the user agent on the server side.