# IE8 Compatibility Mode - document.documentMode

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode

I need a javascript code "document.documentMode" which will have a value of 8 in true IE8 mode and 7 in IE7 mode.

The user agent string will be identical in both cases and will still state IE8.
Note that this JavaScript variable is only available in IE8.

Basically, I must detect when someone is running IE8 (tue) and IE8 (in compatibility mode).

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208837/how-can-i-detect-if-ie8-is-running-in-compatibility-view)

Comment: I did now. thanks. there's any code that you can recommend me?>

Comment: Well, I am not an expert of the topic you are interested about. Just searched your requirement and found that post and thought it might be helpful :)

Comment: Dumb question: Why do you need to know/do this? Normally the page author (you) decide if a page runs in standards or compatibility mode. It's rare that the user needs or needs to switch, and if they do it's their own fault.

Answer (score 2):

"Basically, I must detect when someone is running IE8 (tue) and IE8 (in compatibility mode)."

```
var ie8 = /msie\s+8/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
var mod = document.documentMode;
if (ie8 && mod == 8) {
   alert("found!");
}

// or
var ok = (
    /msie\s+8/i.test(navigator.userAgent) &&
    document.documentMode == 8
);
if (ok) {
    // ...
```